# Remove a + sign from google form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using google forms to keep inventory of medications. With each medication the count has to be done on how many you started with, how many you added/removed, then how many you left. I have the added/removed as multiple choice of 0, -1, and a fill in option. This makes it so as you are going through all the medications 99% of the time it is those two options. But when they are restocking people keep writing '+' to the number. This makes it so none of my scripts work, and it will not share that to other sheets.

How do I remove the '+' from their submissions? I have tried formatting the column, but that only fixes the ones that were in there, not new submissions. Any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rw03hXZuMD19BSG6Q8Q1Vyz6CS6bmFpwa6kut9iYbo4/edit?usp=sharing Here is the link to a copy of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no way of implementing form validation using Google Apps Script (see related questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472877/onsubmit-form-validation), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844107/any-way-to-validate-a-google-form-input)). However, you may be interested in the following proposed workaround:

### Workaround

You can use a `short answer` type of question with a [Response validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en). The response validation, assuming you only admit integers, should be set as follows:

- Regular expression, matches `(-)?\d*`.

It would look like this:

[image: Example form with response validation]

In case a user enters a number such as `+55`, the form will not allow the user to submit it, showing an error that says "Number not valid".

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to see if there was a way to keep the multiple choice because it flows so much faster since 95% of the time we place just 0, 4% -1, then that last 1% is the issue. I will use this though in the mean time!

Answer (score 0):

You have a field in a form where you are expecting the response to be a value but some responses are strings. These are the result of preceeding a value by the "plus" sign ("+").

The following answer demonstrates a method for testing whether a response is a number or a string, and converting the response to a number. This might be used in an onFormSubmit trigger (either at the Form, or the Response Spreadsheet).

The code relies on the Javascript [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator.

---

```
 function so5845243102() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Form Responses 2";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // Column D contains responses that should be values but are occassionally strings.
  // Therefore test before processing.
  // Cell D5 contains an example 
  var resp = sheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  // Logger.log(resp);//DEBUG

  if (typeof resp === 'string') {
    // this is a string
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Response = "+resp+" is a string;  length = "+resp.length+", the first character = "+resp.substring(0, 1));

    // test if first character is a plus sign ("+")
    if (resp.substring(0, 1) ==="+"){

      // exclude the first character
      var shortresp = resp.substring(1,+resp.length);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: the shortened response = "+shortresp);

      // now, convert the shortened response to a number and test it
      var modrespnum =Number(shortresp);

      // test whether the modified value is still a string
      if (typeof modrespnum === 'string'){
        // if a string, then more detailed investigation required;
        Logger.log("DEBUG: Modified response = "+modrespnum+". It is a string - Investigate ");
        return;      
      }
      else{
        // it is NOT a string
        Logger.log("DEBUG: Modified response = "+modrespnum+". It is NOT a string");

        // if not a string, test whether it is a number
        if (typeof modrespnum === 'number') {
          Logger.log("DEBUG: Modified response = "+modrespnum+". It is a number"); 
          return;
        }
        else{
         Logger.log("DEBUG: Modified response = "+modrespnum+". It is NOT a number - Investigate ");
        }
        return;
      }
    }
    else{
      // more investigation required
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Response value = "+resp+" - needs investigation");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey this is awesome, It recognizes the string and removes the sign in the log, but it does not translate to the sheet. I still cant figure it out...

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You're stuck with your form but this code suggests how you could manage the responses. For example, overwrite the string  (`sheet.getRange("D5").setValue(modrespnum);`), or  leave the original intact and write the number into another column (`sheet.getRange("D5").offset(0, 1).setValue(modrespnum);`), or  copy the string to another column (`sheet.getRange("D5").offset(0, 1).setValue(resp);`) and _then_ overwrite the original response. New responses: use `onFormSubmit` trigger or maybe run as a batch?; Existing responses: run it for a given range of responses?

Comment: The issue with this answer is that it will not provide any feedback for the form user. If the user, instead of submitting a number, submits an invalid value (i.e. "1x", "+20", or "+1.251") that answer could be removed or modified using Apps Script, but the user will think that his/her submission was accepted. I'm afraid that the only way of implementing proper Response validation is using another type of response (i.e. short answer)...

Comment: Apologies. I took "_but it does not translate to the sheet._" literally  This looks a classic case of the 80-20 rule. Before changing a question that appears to work most of the time, have you tried editing the question description to explain how to enter a fill-in response, done any analysis about whether this is a case of "round up the usual suspects", tried to correct it through training, considered using a different question for re-stock.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot one of the most obvious solutions. Convert the form to a web-app; you can run a script on the answer and correct it before submission.